# Please help me find the nth term of this series

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey I'd really really like some help with the following series:

$$\int\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n _ $$

First term
$$u_1=-\frac{ln(x-c_1)}{(c_2-c_1)}-\frac{ln(x-c_2)}{(c_1-c_2)}$$

Second term
$$u_2=-\frac{ln(x-c_1)}{(c_2-c_1)(c_3-c_1)}-\frac{ln(x-c_2)}{(c_1-c_2)(c_2-c_3)}-\frac{ln(x-c_3)}{(c_1-c_3)(c_2-c_3)}$$

Third term
$$u_3=-\frac{ln(x-c_1)}{(c_2-c_1)(c_3-c_1)(c_4-c_1)}-\frac{ln(x-c_2)}{(c_1-c_2)(c_2-c_3)(c_2-c_4)}-\frac{ln(x-c_1)}{(c_1-c_3)(c_2-c_3)(c_3-c_4)}-\frac{ln(x-c_4)}{(c_1-c_4)(c_2-c_4)(c_3-c_4)}$$

E.t.c 
All the non x terms are constants (if that helps)

Please help me find the nth term 
Thank you

Alice

Comment: Did you mean $$u_n=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\prod_{i =1}^{n+1}(c_i - x)}$$ in your first equation?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm open to any suggestions, and I'm considering whether it's easier to establish the nth term in terms of the integrated closed version or the partial fraction decomposition version I posted here. Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u_n=-\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_r)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne r}^{n+1} (c_i-c_r)}\right)$$
is the required $n^{th}$ term.

**EDIT**

I am expanding here for $n=1$ and $n=2$.
$$u_1=-\sum_{r=1}^{2}\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_r)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne r}^{2} (c_i-c_r)}\right)$$
$$=-\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_1)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne 1}^{2} (c_i-c_1)}\right)-\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_2)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne 2}^{2} (c_i-c_2)}\right)$$
$$=-\dfrac{\ln(x-c_1)}{c_2-c_1}-\dfrac{\ln(x-c_2)}{c_1-c_2}$$
which is the expression you have given us.

For $n=2$ , we have,
$$u_2 = -\sum_{r=1}^{3}\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_r)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne r}^{3} (c_i-c_r)}\right)$$
$$=-\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_1)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne 1}^{3} (c_i-c_1)}\right)-\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_2)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne 2}^{3} (c_i-c_2)}\right)-\left(\dfrac{\ln(x-c_3)}{\prod_{i=1\\i\ne 3}^{3} (c_i-c_3)}\right)$$
$$=-\dfrac{\ln(x-c_1)}{(c_2-c_1)(c_3-c_1)}-\dfrac{\ln(x-c_2)}{(c_1-c_2)(c_3-c_2)}-\dfrac{\ln(x-c_3)}{(c_1-c_3)(c_2-c_3)}$$
which is the expression you have given us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this answer is wrong because of the denominator, everything else is fine. Thank you for the attempt, I will continue asking for help but any small bit is really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @AliceLindén, you can expand it for some small values of $n$ like $1,2,\cdots$ and verify its correctness.

Comment: @AliceLindén, I have edited the answer to show you its correctness for small values, check it out.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect. You've been very helpful. Cheer!

Comment: @AliceLindén, You're welcome.